# Including eps files written on Xara

Tags: pdf, graphics, eps

I'm trying to submit a preprint to arXiv, and the compiler there fails to convert it to PDF (although WinEdt at home has no complaints). Moreover, the log file didn't provide me with meaningful information as to what precisely had gone wrong. My theory is that their compiler doesn't like my eps files, which contain images drawn using [Xara](http://www.xara.com/) (I can think of no other reason why my preprint would compile to a ps but not to a pdf). There are a lot of eps files included- 131 of them.

> Has anyone encountered similar problems submitting papers with eps images drawn using Xara? Is that indeed the likely problem? Is there a fix? Is there a fix that can be carried out without editing 131 eps files by hand?

**UPDATE**: I think I figured it out, by constructing a minimal failing example, and forcing it to work. It's the TIFF preview which causes the problem. Now I'm stripping it from each eps file, one by one...

Comment: Does arXiv allow you to submit `*.eps` files?

Comment: I submit a tar file which includes a tex file together with the eps files which it calls with \includegraphics{} commands.

Comment: Could you post your solution as answer and accept so that your question is removed from the list of unanswered questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The arXiv site doesn't say much about how they actually generate pdf. But it sounds as if they would use latex-dvips-distiller. In this case my first suspect would be the fonts of the eps. But without a complete minimal failing example document and one of the problematic eps it will be very difficult to say more.

Comment: I believe I figured out the problem. It's the leading TIFF preview which is causing the mess. Now to strip it from all 131 eps files, and hope that there is no other problem...

Comment: @Daniel: Would you consider answering your own question if you have resolved the problem, and subsequently accepting the answer, so that it's removed from the list of unanswered questions. We're trying to clean up some old unanswered questions. Thanks for the understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Xara is...Try converting your eps files to pdf (Use psfrag and fragmaster, if you can't find another way) and then submit again with the pdfs. That will at least diagnose the  problem...